# Frequency of some element in array

Tags: php, arrays

How to check what is the number of occurs of some certain element in array 
For example I have such array:

```
Array (
    [0] => esco
    [1] => angebot
    [2] => ihren
    [3] => parkett
    [4] => maivholzdielen
    [5] => auswahl 
    [6] => ihnen
        ... etc...);
```

Now I want to find out what is the number of occurs of array element i.e. "parkett" ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[array_count_values()](http://php.net/array-count-values) has you covered.

Comment: ok, but now I got some associative array. Question is how to pull out result: how many times some specific element occur (in my case "parkett") ?

Comment: The "specific element" is the key in the array. So say you have `$count` is the result of `array_count_values()`, you'd get `$count['parkett']` is the number of times that word appears.

Answer (score 0):

The following will assign a value to $Count which wil be the number of objects in the array that match the word: "parkett".

```
$Count = array_count_values($YourArray, "parkett");
```